# Mac OS photos : programatic access to the recently deleted photos folder?

Tags: python

In order to do a deep learning model auto classifying my pictures, I would like to make a copy of all my deleted photos in Mac's photo (unfortunately the "recover" photo put it back on the main photo album, so I loose the fact it was deleted at first).

How can I access the deleted photos ?
Having a look on the "photos" package, the data organisation is quite obscure.

At the same time : how can I access the "favorite" tag on each photo (my model should classify in favorite/deleted/not deleted).

I am rather pythonista at first.

Thx,
Romain.

### EDIT #1

I found this package : https://pypi.org/project/osxphotos/#osxphotos
which should do the trick, but I've got an error :

```
import osxphotos
path = "/Users/romain/Pictures/Photothèque.photoslibrary/"
photosdb = osxphotos.PhotosDB(path)
```

Gives :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osxphotos/photosdb/photosdb.py in _process_database4(self)
    798             try:
--> 799                 self._dbphotos[uuid]["imageDate"] = datetime.fromtimestamp(row[5] + td)
    800             except ValueError:

ValueError: year 0 is out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-42282d7447c7> in <module>
      1 import osxphotos
      2 path = "/Users/romain/Pictures/Photothèque.photoslibrary/"
----> 3 photosdb = osxphotos.PhotosDB(path)

/Applications/anaconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osxphotos/photosdb/photosdb.py in __init__(self, dbfile, *dbfile_)
    287 
    288         if int(self._db_version) <= int(_PHOTOS_4_VERSION):
--> 289             self._process_database4()
    290         else:
    291             self._process_database5()

/Applications/anaconda3/envs/python38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osxphotos/photosdb/photosdb.py in _process_database4(self)
    799                 self._dbphotos[uuid]["imageDate"] = datetime.fromtimestamp(row[5] + td)
    800             except ValueError:
--> 801                 self._dbphotos[uuid]["imageDate"] = datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)
    802 
    803             self._dbphotos[uuid]["mainRating"] = row[6]

TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

## Edit#2

I modified the file  :

```
#self._dbphotos[uuid]["imageDate"] = datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)
self._dbphotos[uuid]["imageDate"] = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of the package you referenced.  First, thanks for opening an issue for this bug -- I've fixed the bug and the test case that should have caught this in the first place.  I've also added a new "intrash" property so you can access the recently deleted photos.  You'll need to update to [v0.30.0](https://github.com/RhetTbull/osxphotos/releases/tag/v0.30.0) either via git or do a `pip install --upgrade osxphotos` if you used pip.

Here's a short but complete program that will export the deleted photos, not deleted photos, and favorite photos.  It lacks error checking etc. but should be enough to get you started.

```py
import os
import osxphotos

# update this to your export path
export_path = "/Users/romain/Desktop/export"


def export_photos(export_path, photo_list):
    # create destination directory if needed
    if not os.path.isdir(export_path):
        os.makedirs(export_path)

    for photo in photo_list:
        if not photo.ismissing:
            print(f"Exporting {photo.original_filename} to {export_path}")
            photo.export(export_path, photo.original_filename)
        else:
            print(f"Skipping missing photo {photo.original_filename}")


def main():
    photosdb = osxphotos.PhotosDB()

    not_deleted = photosdb.photos()
    favorite = [p for p in photosdb.photos() if p.favorite]
    deleted = photosdb.photos(intrash=True)

    print("Exporting not deleted")
    export_photos(os.path.join(export_path, "not_deleted"), not_deleted)

    print("Exporting deleted")
    export_photos(os.path.join(export_path, "deleted"), deleted)

    print("Exporting favorites")
    export_photos(os.path.join(export_path, "favorite"), favorite)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```